# Im using ubuntu 18.04 in my hp laptop . Ubuntu is stuck after shut down

Tags: 18.04, shutdown

My ubuntu 18.04 has been getting hang when i click on power off since 20 days. I searched on many websites but the problem did not solve . Also i tried to shut down with terminal but result is same. Pease tell me the solutuon and also i request to ubuntu team to solve this issue . I am using power button (press it for 10 sec) for power off.

Comment: is your screen computer froze or are you stuck on the " Ubuntu . . . . ." disconnection page (in a infinite loop)? It can help a lot some people to help you about the issue(s) process(es)

Comment: I don't know about that but before shut down , there is no running process. After pressing power off or by commanding , my cursor gets invisible and screen get stuck and at last i have to press power butoon at least 10 seconds